# How to subscribe to Polymer paper-dropdown-menu value change event? (Angular2)

Tags: angular, polymer

The [paper-input](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input) component has a "changed" event that you can use to implement 2-way binding. I'm looking for an equivalent for [paper-dropdown-menu](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-dropdown-menu). The paper-dropdown-menu api provides the "value" property as a getter, but not as an event.

Here is the standard paper-dropdown-menu declaration:

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="Your favourite pastry">
  <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content">
    <paper-item>Croissant</paper-item>
    <paper-item>Donut</paper-item>
    <paper-item>Financier</paper-item>
    <paper-item>Madeleine</paper-item>
  </paper-listbox>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

[paper-listbox](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-listbox) has an event like the one described ("iron-select"), but the event data does not tell you which paper-dropdown-menu it is a child of.

So far the best way I've been able to accomplish data binding is by listening to all paper-listbox "iron-select" events, and then grabbing the values of all dropdowns every time.

In Angular2:

```
/* template */

<paper-dropdown-menu #dropdown1 label="Your favourite pastry">
  <paper-listbox (iron-select)="onSelectDropdown($event)" class="dropdown-content">
    <paper-item>Croissant</paper-item>
    <paper-item>Donut</paper-item>
    <paper-item>Financier</paper-item>
    <paper-item>Madeleine</paper-item>
  </paper-listbox>
</paper-dropdown-menu>

//and another 2...

/* class */

@ViewChild('dropdown1') dropdown1:any;
@ViewChild('dropdown2') dropdown2:any;
@ViewChild('dropdown3') dropdown3:any;

onSelectDropdown(event:any){
  setTimeout(()=>{
    this.data = {
     thing1: this.dropdown1.nativeElement.value;
     thing2: this.dropdown2.nativeElement.value;
     thing3: this.dropdown3.nativeElement.value;
    }
  }, 0);
}
```

This does not seem like a very elegant way to do it, especially since I have to wrap the getter ("value") calls in a timeout. This is because the event fires before it propagates to the parent (paper-dropdown-menu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bindable change event would be nice, but these could be modest improvements on the current approach:

Rather than the timeout, you could get the value directly from the listbox event (this also supports multi-select, if that's desirable):

```
onSelectDropdown(event:any){
    console.log("selected item(s)", event.target.selectedItems);
}
```

To determine which list it came from you could provide different handlers for the dropdowns, or specify it manually for the handler:

```
<paper-dropdown-menu #dropdown1 label="Your favourite pastry">
    <paper-listbox (iron-select)="onSelectDropdown($event,'dropdown1')" class="dropdown-content">
...
<paper-dropdown-menu #dropdown2 label="Your favourite cheese">
    <paper-listbox (iron-select)="onSelectDropdown($event,'dropdown2')" class="dropdown-content">
```